# Is there a mouseover fix for when the browser renders the element under the mouse?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, dom-events

It seems in most (all?) browsers, if the browser renders an element with an mouseEnter/mouseOver listener under the mouse, the event will not be triggered. So we now have the mouse over an element and the code doesn't act as though the mouse is over the element.

Is there an easy fix for this?

Comment: Have you tried programmatically triggering the mouseover event once you add your dynamic element?

Comment: @j08691 I want a general solution to what I view is a browser flaw. I ask to be notified when my mouse is over an element. The browser renders the element under the mouse. Therefore the mouse is over the element. I am not notified. That's the problem I'd like to fix. I could change how my app works or is written. That's not what I want.

Comment: You may be taking the word mouseover too literally. The mouseover event is triggered upon movement, not just when the mouse pointer happens to be over an element. The [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#event-type-mouseover) actually states that movement must occur, "A user agent MUST dispatch this event when a pointing device is moved onto the boundaries of an element." so I wouldn't call this a browser flaw.

Comment: @j08691 I am familiar with the specs. I specified "what **I** view is a browser flaw". In that it's my own personal view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to monitor all HTML nodes for changes that could possibly move an element on the page to be under the cursor. When any such change happens, you could use [`Document.elementFromPoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint) to find the hovered element and then [manually trigger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#Triggering_built-in_events) a `mouseover` event on that element:

```js
function dispatchArtificialMouseover() {
  const elementMouseIsOver = document.elementFromPoint(
    event.clientX,
    event.clientY
  );
  const mouseoverEvent = new MouseEvent("mouseover");
  elementMouseIsOver.dispatchEvent(mouseoverEvent);
}

const observerConfig = {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  characterData: true,
  subtree: true
};

const observer = new MutationObserver(dispatchArtificialMouseover);
const rootElement = document.body;
observer.observe(rootElement, observerConfig);
```

However, I would guess that listening to all changes on the page will slow the page down if anything changes frequently, such as when the user types text into an input.

Comment: I think this is a good start. Apparently MutationObserver was designed to batch mutations for performance considerations. We'd also need to keep track of last event dispatch to ensure we aren't sending redundant updates.